# How to write data in Excel by WebDriver with Java using TestNG framework and Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, selenium-webdriver, testng

I want to store username and password in Excel whatever I will type in any application using WebDriver. I am using TestNG framework and Apache POI to write data to Excel. But I am getting `Null pointer exception`. Please tell me how to work WebDriver with Excel.

```
public class Test {

    private static WebDriver driver;
    static String username="abc";
    static String password="abf123";

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            driver.get("any url");

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='txtUserName']")).sendKeys(username);

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='txtPwd']")).sendKeys(password);

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Userpass.xls");

            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

            HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.createSheet("POI WorkSheet");

            HSSFRow row1 = worksheet.createRow((short) 0);

            HSSFCell cell1 = row1.createCell((short) 0);

            cell1.setCellValue(username);

            HSSFCell cell2 = row1.createCell((short) 1);

            cell2.setCellValue(password);

            workbook.write(fos);

            fos.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Test
    public void f() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Where about are you getting the Null pointer?

Comment: when i debug my program i am getting Null pointer exception here.driver.get("any url");

Comment: maybe try "WebDriver driver = new WebDriver();" not sure if that will solve the problem though.

Comment: I guess you need an instance of WebDriver (try "private static WebDriver driver = new WebDriver();").

Comment: When i run my application with TestNG test it is not giving any error but excel sheet is not generating.Please help me what to do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the following lines in your code

```
HSSFRow row1 = worksheet.createRow((short) 0);
HSSFCell cell1 = row1.createCell((short) 0);
cell1.setCellValue(username);
HSSFCell cell2 = row1.createCell((short) 1);
cell2.setCellValue(password);
```

with

```
HSSFRow row1 = worksheet.createRow(0);
row1.createCell(0).setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("username"));
row1.createCell(1).setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("password"));
```

you will get the desired output.